# How do i change the Action attribute in a form field? HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently working on a web application, where i need to be able to take a picture in a browser using a mobile device. 
I'am currently able to upload this picture to my storage on googlecloud, but i am having some troubles with the URL of said picture. The URL of the picture is defined in an action(HTML attribute). And im struggling to see how this action field can be dynamic. 
It seems i cant put in the variable name for my URL in the action field.

Is there any other way to do this?
Im sorry in advance for my bad english.

```
<form id="BilleddeUpload" action="url" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" accept="/*" name="file">
    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    function gogogoogle(){
        var billedenavn = document.getElementById("BilledeUpload");
        var url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/notgonnaputreallinkhere/"
        + prompt("Insert picture name here.");

        billedenavn.action=url;
}
</script>

<p>Billede på google cloud </p>
<button onclick="gogogoogle()">
    Hvad skal den hedde????
</button>
```

Comment: `BilledeUpload !== BilleddeUpload`.

Comment: i understand what u meant. U cheeky one.

Comment: Cheeky? It's not cheeky at all, you've written the id incorrectly, JS can't recognize those two names as the same name.

Comment: Just a really vague answer, as i didnt understand what u meant after reading it 4 times i got it.

Comment: It's not an answer, it's a comment, and it is also chrystal clear if you know JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have defined a variable to hold a reference to the form `billedenavn`.

This line

```
 var billedenavn = document.getElementById("BilledeUpload")
```

and a few lines later you wrote

```
  document.getElementById("BilledeUpload").action = url;
```

which contains a typo in the form ID. But why not directly write:

```
  billedenavn.action = url;
```

Comment: Thank you!  Your answer combined with @RGhanbari 's answer made it work.

Comment: I have updated your code and fixed the problem with `</script>` closing tag

Comment: and also made the code work as typed in my answer. Unfortunatly, you can not accept two answers. You may however, upvote both answers and select one as the correct answer

Comment: I have upvoted you! @Ahmad thank you for taking a little time helping me with my stupidity.

Answer (score 0):

their is some syntax error.

put `function` [and it's body] into `script` tag,
and change `form` `id` from `BilleddeUpload` to `BilledeUpload`.